# UHD B210 phase synchronisation between radios

Tags: usrp, uhd

I have two B210 radios sharing a 10MHz external master clock and 1pps time signal.  I have noticed that each time I start a receive stream simultaneously on both radios they are out by a random but quantised phase variation.
For example if the internal master clock rate is set to 16MHz and the sample rate is 1Mhz then the phase difference is a random multiple of Pi/6. Note this is between different B210 radios - there is no such variation between the two RF channels of the B210.
I need the radios to be in phase lock, not just frequency lock, for the measurements I am making.  My work around at the moment is to inject a calibration signal into all the radios at the start of each capture to measure this difference then compensate for it by adjusting the samples in software.

Is there something I have missed in the UHD API which allows me to lock the radios together so they do not have this variation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming at all. Perhaps electrical engineering site would be more appropriate?

Comment: Good point - I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of providing the phase synchronisation between radios as they have different local synthesizers.

From USRP Driver Manual:

> After tuning the RF front-ends, each local oscillator may have a random phase offset due to the dividers in the VCO/PLL chains. This offset will remain constant after the device has been initialized, and will remain constant until the device is closed or re-tuned.

More here http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_sync.html